# .NET naming conventions

Tags: .net, vb.net, coding-style

I am supporting and developing a large application.  This question relates specifically to naming conventions.

The previous developer used Pascal Casing, underscores for variable names and a few other techniques, which seem to be frowned upon these days.

My question is: should I continue using the conventions that he used for consistency or introduce conventions that don't seem to be frowned upon as described here: http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards.aspx at the expense of inconsistency for at least some time.

I am trying to refactor the code as I go along so maybe I should introduce new conventions in new areas of the application and continue refactoring the code by replacing frowned upon conventions with modern conventions?

Perhaps I am overthinking this.

Comment: I'd say that link you referenced is as pretty good starting point.  I've done quite a bit of .NET development over the years and the article seems to a be pretty standard.

Comment: @BrianB, would you start introducing the new conventions straight away at the expense of being inconsistent?

Comment: It really depends on how bad the old code was, how much of it there is and how the projects are set up. If the old code was written using Java style camel casing everywhere, I'd be more inclined to switch over to something that is consistent with the core Framework libraries.  Some level of inconsistency may be unavoidable, particularly if you're using 3rd party libraries by different vendors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the old code is consistent, keep it consistent, different style all over the place makes it even more confusing.

If you are going to change, make it a work item, schedule it and do it all at once.

You can of course find arguments for making a gradually change. If you can convince your self that you will complete the renaming by working in small steps where you need to work on the code anyway, go ahead. But to be honest, how many of those gradually transforming code process get finished before there is an updated style guide line and you start of in a third style before cleaning up the first change.

If your code is already in an inconsistent style there is even more compelling reasons to clean up the mess right now before it gets even worse.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have time to schedule this in at the moment.  Therefore I should continue writing code with the old conventions for the time being.  Then at a later date, schedule some time to change all of it (including the code written between now and then)?

Comment: Yep, that is how I generally reason (but maybe not how I live every day). But as with all black/white advises you can always be a little bit more nuanced in practice, especially if you have more details guiding your decision. I.e. legacy modules and "new" modules where you can draw a line in your design work.